# No reverse match for password_reset_confirm

Tags: django, reverse, forgot-password

I know there has been a large no.of posts on this same issue,
I have tried some suggestions posted here, but nothing seems to work,
now my doubt is whether my keyword arguments are in the right form:

`'{'uidb64': b'MTE', 'token': '455-d9bba75261f76a0c7efe'}'`

Does the `b` up there( in `uidb64` ) indicate anything wrong, or is it fine?

If this is fine, then what is going wrong?

Comment: can you post your urls.py file for this route?